# Merge multiple files keeping file name as column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple files in a directory. I want to merge them in a way such that the rows are merged together, and file names are kept as column headers.
For example, file1 looks like

```
ENSG1     12
ENSG2     13
ENSG3     14
```

file2 looks like

```
ENSG1     13
ENSG2     14
ENSG4     15
```

I'm looking forward to an output like

```
          file1      file2
ENSG1      12         13
ENSG2      13         14
ENSG3      14         0/na
ENSG4      0/na       15
```

Do you have any idea how to do this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to perform an outer join. `result = file1.merge(file2, on='col1', how='outer')` Then you can rename your columns. Also, you can find more resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do that using `concat`:

```
dfs = []
for f in ["file1", "file2"]: # iterate the relevant files here
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep = "\s+", index_col=0)
    df.columns = [f]
    dfs.append(df)
res = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

The output it:

```
       file1  file2
ENSG1   12.0   13.0
ENSG2   13.0   14.0
ENSG3   14.0    NaN
ENSG4    NaN   15.0
```